# Can an ASP Repeater cause Javascript to loop through a function multiple times when no loop is present in the code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I am using the jQuery toggle method to show or hide a div with a text box in it.  The html is inside an ASP repeater. I am a UX developer, so .net is not something I know to much about.  When the click event is fired the area expands 3 times in a row and then closes, the expected behavior is to open once and remain that way until the next time the event is invoked, which should close it.   There is no loop or each method in the JavaScript.  Can a repeater cause the JavaScript to fire multiple times when a click event is invoked?  Hwo do you avoid it?

```
<div class="optionDivClick">
<asp:Label ID="EvaluatorAssessmentQuestionLabel" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
<h3 class="commentExpand">
<i class="icon-plus-sign" id="optionEvaCommentImg" runat="server"
visible="<%# (((Library.UserCategory)Container.DataItem).EvaluatorAssessmentComment).Answer.Visible %>"></i></h3>
<div class="expand">
<eDevCustom:TextBoxWithSpellCheck runat="server" ID="EvaluatorCommenteDevTextBox" ShowBorder="true"
Visible="<%# (((Library.UserCategory)Container.DataItem).EvaluatorAssessmentComment).Answer.Visible %>"
ReadOnly="<%#  (((Library.UserCategory)Container.DataItem).EvaluatorAssessmentComment).Answer.ReadOnly %>"
Text="<%# (((Library.UserCategory)Container.DataItem).EvaluatorAssessmentComment).Answer.AnswerText %>" />
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="UserCatID" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,    "UserCatID") %>' />
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="UserDescription" value='<%#   DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserDescription") %>' />
</div>
</div>

$('.commentExpand').on('click', function () {
$('i', this).toggleClass('icon-plus-sign icon-minus-sign');
var target = $(this).parent().children('.expand');
$(target).slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: why dont you do it with ajax toolkit

Comment: i think you are applying click event for class `.commentExpand` if your class is in `itemtemplate` of repeater then it can fire multiple times